# I want to add shadow below header in storefront theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, storefront

I want to add shadow below header in storefront theme in wordpress. I think this is easy but i dont know the class or id used in the theme for header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your element inspector to find the right class.

Right click: inspect

A good tip is to use Firfox in combination with the firebug addon. With this setup your are able to copy the selector path. Goodluck!

Comment: I am using my mobile phone to edit it...   I will be thankful if you can do this for me.   My website is - store.codebla.com